# Meteor: how to put client code in cordova block

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm developing a hybrid application which gets an ID from a nfc tag and then show the data (taken from server side) in the app.

**How do I actually load a template (defined in client/view/template.html) since the following code is run only on mobile?**

```
if (Meteor.isCordova){
    Meteor.startup(function(){ 

        var onNfc = function(nfcEvent) {
            var tag = nfcEvent.tag,
                ndefMessage = tag.ndefMessage;

            var strMessage = JSON.stringify(ndefMessage);
            alert(strMessage); // show the gathered data

            messagePayload= JSON.parse(strMessage)[0].payload;
            msgPayloadStr = nfc.bytesToString(messagePayload); // decode payload
            // alert(msgPayloadStr); // show the gathered data

            // show the data on client side
            // TODO
        };

        nfc.addNdefListener(
            onNfc,
            function(){}, // success
            function(){} // failure
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: use a router and go to the desired route?

Comment: the problem is that basically I can't manage to transfer the data to the client side, it's not about loading the template